# Natural sorting of alphanumeric values in sqlite using android

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I have a list of names of starts with characters and end with numbers like: -

```
ka1, ka10, ka 2, ka, sa2, sa1, sa10, p1a10, 1kb, p1a2, p1a11, p1a.
```

I want to sort it in natural order, that is: -

```
1kb, ka, ka1, ka 2, ka10, p1a, p1a2, p1a10, p1a11, sa1, sa2, sa10.
```

The main problem I am seeing here is no delimiter between text and numeric part, there also a chance of without numeric part also.

I am using sqlite in android, I can do sorting using java after fetching points by cacheing cursor data, but I am using(recommended to use) cursor adapter.

Please suggest a query for sorting or is there any way to apply sorting in cursor?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @SKBasha check my answer

Answer (score 5):

I tried below query for Natural sorting:

```
SELECT 
    item_no
FROM
    items
ORDER BY 
   LENGTH(item_no), item_no;
```

It worked for me in Sqlite db too. Please see this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-sorting/), for more details.

Comment: Not perfect, but a good clean way to natural sort numbers. Not sure about letters and decimals, but certainly to get something like "202" to show up before "1001". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose using regex replacement adding zeros, creating temporary table of original and corresponding values, then follow this link for sorting it: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-sort-table-by-columns-in-python/
tip for regex add as many zeros after last letter, but limit the number of total digits for predicted maximum number of digits. If You need help with regex as well, provide exact info of valid and invalid values, so can halp with that too.
PS if want to be sure that zeros goes before last digits search for char from the end

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

You can use different ways - Some of are mentioned below:

**BIN Way**

```
SELECT 
tbl_column, 
BIN(tbl_column) AS binray_not_needed_column
FROM db_table
ORDER BY binray_not_needed_column ASC , tbl_column ASC
```

---

**Cast Way**

```
SELECT 
tbl_column, 
CAST(tbl_column as SIGNED) AS casted_column
FROM db_table
ORDER BY casted_column ASC , tbl_column ASC
```

or try the solution:

> There are a whole lot of solutions out there if you hit up Google, and
>   you can, of course, just use the natsort() function in PHP, but it's
>   simple enough to accomplish natural sorting in MySQL: sort by length
>   first, then the column value.
>
> Query: `SELECT alphanumeric, integer FROM sorting_test ORDER BY LENGTH(alphanumeric), alphanumeric` from [here](http://www.copterlabs.com/natural-sorting-in-mysql/)

Comment: This does not ignore spaces, and does not handle values with a different number of digits correctly.